# Can a value be uninitialized, but still defined, in Perl?

Tags: perl, undefined, defined, perl5.10

Running ActiveState Perl 5.10.1 on win32.

How is it that this code:

```
die(defined($r->unparsed_uri =~ '/(logout.pl)?$'));
```

...dies with `1`, whereas changing the same line to say this:

```
die($r->unparsed_uri =~ '/(logout.pl)?$');
```

...dies with `Use of uninitialized value in die`?

How is it `defined` yet `uninitialized`?  I thought uninitialized meant undefined.

Comment: I'm betting it's just some funky scalar-vs-list-context thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, the matching operation is taking place in scalar context.  In the second case, it's taking place in array context, almost as if you had written:

```
my @groups = $r->unparsed_uri =~ '/(logout.pl)?$';
die @groups;
```

If `$r->unparsed_uri` matches the pattern, but `$1` is undefined because the matched string ended with "/", then @groups will be an array of length 1, containing the single element `undef`.

Put it all together, it's as if you'd said:

```
die(undef);
```

Comment: Oh, and I should have mentioned, if it's not obvious, that you can get the behavior you were expecting with die(scalar($r->unparsed_uri =~ '/(logout.pl)?$'));

Answer (score 2):

Do you have warnings enabled?

Given

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict; use warnings;

my $uri;

die(defined($uri =~ '/(logout.pl)?$'));
```

I get

```
Use of uninitialized value $uri in pattern match (m//) at E:\t.pl line 7.
1 at E:\t.pl line 7.
```

which explains what is going on.

`$uri` is not defined, so you get a warning for using that in `m//`. Because `$uri` is not defined, the result of the match is false but **defined**. Hence, `defined` returns true and `die` outputs `1`.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be `undef =~ /(bar)?/` - I think `"foo" =~ /(bar)?/` could produce the reported behavior as well.

Comment: @fennec I just described why the OP saw the behavior he saw. What is inside the `defined(...)` is false but defined. `$r->unparsed_uri` is not both uninitialized and defined as the title of the question implies.